# Meaning of asterisk and arrow symbols in Gradle dependencies tree

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have run `gradlew` command to get Gradle *dependencies tree*:

> gradlew.bat app:dependencies

On output I am getting different type of symbols attached with each dependency:

```
 com.twotoasters.servos:util-otto:1.0.0
 com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0 (*)
 com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0 -> 25.0.0
```

Some dependencies are without any symbol, some are with `(*)` and `->`.
What do these symbols mean?

I have tried to search this, but failed to find any help on this.

Answer (score 34):

`(*)` stands next to the dependency, which has already been imported though other artifact, thus resulting in duplication.

At the end of the output of `./gradlew :app:dependencies` you can see this:[image]

`->` stands next to the dependency, which has already been imported through other artifact, **but with a newer version**. Gradle will prefer the newer version.

Hence, `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0 -> 25.0.0` would mean, that `25.0.0` version is already imported, but particularly that artifact is dependent on an older `23.2.0` version.

See explanation by [Egor Andreevici](https://twitter.com/egorand) from his [*"Making the most of your Gradle Builds"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RNXngQY5Dc&feature=youtu.be&list=PL4ebO4PmeAi4MgpaaK9Hej0P6ooIhmfms&t=1301) talk from Droidcon Italy 2017.

Comment: Thanks, so if I am getting these symbols, then i need to exclude these libraries from that library which contain these? and a perfect `gradle tree` will not have any of these symbols?

Comment: I do not see issues with `(*)`, because they do not affect on your dex size, whereas `->` is a clear sign to you, that you are *needlessly* enlarging apk's dex size. Removing that dependency is not straightforward, because you cannot be sure, that the module that was dependent on an older version would function as expected on a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

`->` means from version  `23.2.0` to `25.0.0`
its useful when running gradle in offline mode so it will use the first cached version that is available 
`(*)` im not sure but i think it is for downloading and compiling all of the following library family (core,etc...) also there is `+` which is used instead of version code which will use the latest version that is available